# Add "flow" to geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to plot the "flow" of individuals between two groups at certain timepoints.

In the following example:

```
d1=data.frame(c(1:6),
              c("A","B","A","A","B","A"),
              c("A","B","B","A","B","B")
              )

names(d1)=c("id","time1","time2")

require(reshape2)
m1=melt(d1,id.vars="id")

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(m1,aes(x=variable,fill=value))+
  geom_bar(stat="count",width = 0.5)
```

the individuals numbered 3 and 6 "switch" from group A to group B between observations "time1" and "time2". I am searching for a possibility to plot this. Tried geom_polygon but was not successful.

Here is what I like to get:
2 individuals staying in group A and 2 individuals switching to group 2.

[image: [1]]

A more complex example can be seen here: flow of voters between two elections.

[[2] http://cdn1.salzburg24.at/2013/05/Waehlerstroeme-650x435.jpg](http://cdn1.salzburg24.at/2013/05/Waehlerstroeme-650x435.jpg)

Is there a way to achieve this with ggplot?

Comment: The search term that will help you is "Sankey diagram", or "Sankey chart". There's no native geom for that in ggplot2, but there are other packages with a method to generate Sankey charts *e.g.* `networkD3`.

Comment: Is this an [alluvial diagram](http://bc.bojanorama.pl/2014/03/alluvial-diagrams/)?  There is a package called *alluvial* that creates alluvial diagrams.  It looks like someone is working on a *ggplot2* extension [here](https://github.com/corybrunson/ggalluvial).

Comment: Thank you you alluvial diagram is exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks aosmith!

This produced the result I expected:

```
require(alluvial)

d2=aggregate(d1[,2], 
             by= d1[, c('time1','time2')], 
             FUN=function(x) length(x))

names(d2)[3]="Freq"

alluvial(d2[,1:2],freq=d2$Freq)
```